# "Variable not found" error issued by the shell

Tags: shell, variables, initialization

```
if [ "$1" = "" ]
then
       echo -n "Gib das Startkapital ein: "
       read kapital
else
       kapital  = $1
fi

echo $kapital
```

When I say kapital = $1 it says that this variable does not exist:

```
$ sh zins.sh
zins.sh: 16: zins.sh kapital: not found
```

Comment: @anubhava I get a empty string... .

Comment: `kapital="$1"` (no spaces around `=`)

Comment: "it says that this variable does not exist:" -- Actually no, it says that the *command* named `kapital` is not found in `PATH`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Unlike free-format languages like C, the shell is white-space sensitive in many places, and one of them is the `=` in assignments. Use

```
kapital=$1
```

and it will work.